# Dynamically loaded php, .load(), is not working with jquery already on the page

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my jquery:

```
$(function(){
    $('.messagediv').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find('.deletelistenchatcontainer').css({'display':'block'});
    $(this).find('.hidefordeletelistenchat').css({'display':'none'});
    }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).find('.deletelistenchatcontainer').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).find('.hidefordeletelistenchat').css({'display':'block'});
    }); 
    });
```

Here is my php:

```
$id2 = mysql_real_escape_string($id2);
                $getdata8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM musicbook WHERE identify='$identify' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
                $numrowsgetdata = mysql_num_rows($getdata8);
                if ((mysql_num_rows($getdata8))<1)
                {
                echo "<i>Be the first to say something?</i><p/>"; 
                }
                while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata8))
                {
                $id8 = $row8['id'];
                $name8 = $row8['name'];
                $message8 = $row8['message'];
                $message10 = nl2br($message8);
                $date8 = $row8['date'];
                if ($name8==$username)
                {
                echo "
                <section class='hover'>
                <div class='messagediv' style='background:#1A1A1A;'><div style='padding:5px;'>$message10<br/>
                <div style='margin-top:4px; font-size:.8em; float:left;'><div class='hidefordeletelistenchat' style='float:left;'><a href='http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/$name8' style='color:white;'>$name8</a><font style='color:#D6D6D6'> on $date8</font></div>
                <div class='deletelistenchatcontainer' style='float:left;color:#FFF;display:none;z-index:10;background:#1a1a1a'><input type='hidden' id='wpm2' value='$id8'><img src='cross.png' style='float:left;' alt='PearlSquirrel'/><span class='hoverdeletetext' onclick='LinkOnClick4($id8);'>Delete</span></div></div></div></div>
                </section>
                ";
                }
                else
                {
                echo "
                <div class='messagediv'><div style='padding:5px;'>$message10<br/>
                <div style='margin-top:4px; font-size:.8em; float:left;'><div style='float:left;'><a href='http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/$name8' style='color:white;'>$name8</a><font style='color:#D6D6D6'> on $date8</font></div>
                </div></div></div>";
                }
                }
                if($numrowsgetdata >= 20)
                {
                echo "<div id='loadingcomments'><img src='loading.gif' style='height:30px; width:30px;'></div>";
                }
```

The above code works properly.  However, this is a user comment system.  After the user deletes a comment, I reload a div with the same above php function, but when i do this, the jquery that I have above no longer works with the dynamically generated content.  I know that is is a problem with content loaded with the .load() attribute, which I am using, but does anyone know how to make this work properly?  Would I have to use a .live() attribute, or something else?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use .get() instead. It will work.

Comment: So would it be $(this).get('.deletelistenchatcontainer').css({'display':'block'});?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.  .live() was what I needed.